# Android type_system_overlay not covering entire screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-service

I have been banging my head on this issue for a week now. Various google searches revealed possible solutions but nothing worked.

I would post a link to my app, but I am sure that is not allowed. 
Simple app: press a button and it activates a translucent colored overlay.

The issue:

When the overlay is activated, and if the navigation bar is transparent, it does not cover/go behind the navigation bar.

Example: You can see the navigation bar is not covered. The transparent blue is the overlay.

[image: example of issue.]

In main activity after super and setting content view:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TintOverlayService.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

In `TintOverlayService.class`

```
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    windowManager = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    mTopView = (LinearLayout) li.inflate(R.layout.red_overlay, null, false);
    mTopView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colorCode.replace("#", tintValue)));

   WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

This `Color.parseColor(colorCode.replace("#", tintValue))` just applies a user selected color and opacity level.

XML for `red_overlay` layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#40370000"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.TranslucentDecor"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >
</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried various `WindowManager.LayoutParams`, layouts, custom themes, View flags, the Immersive view thing. I am now at a loss with a headache.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: One solution would be to hide the navigation bar. Please refer link : 
https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html

Comment: I have the same problem. Any news?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was add two flags to the parameters:

WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS;

```
int LayoutParamFlags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS;

WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    densityDpi * 6,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                    LayoutParamFlags,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```